# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer : Unable to read multiple property files

Tags: java, spring, property-files

Below is the part of spring-context.xml where PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean is defined:

```
<bean id="propertyResource" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:property-files/config-info.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:property-files/biservices-config.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:dao-config.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:environmentLocator.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

However, after putting a breakpoint @ `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#setLocations` I didn't find all the property files being passed to the setter method.

[image]

Please note that the file environmentLocator.properties and dao-config.properties are present in different jar files, although they are on the classpath. 
What could be the issue?

Comment: Use `<context:property-placeholder location="<comma-seperated-list>">` instead.